# PermGen space with Maven + Tomcat hot deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

We have a maven project that uses profiles to build artifact that suits dev/qa/prod environtments, It uses Spring for dependency injection.
I make hot deploys, so being that it reloads whenever the application war is changed I have made the following change to my maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${my.tomcat.path}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but 50% of the times I got so often this error in the tomcat:

```
Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:830)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1725)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1545)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what happens when the previous application can't be properly undeployed due to resource leaks or other reasons. You can either try to get it to undeploy properly (Tomcat even tells about some leaks in the logs), or just forget it and not do hot deploys.